# Display file name for custom styled input file using jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel, bulma

I want to show the file name of input file

```js
$("#imgInp").change(function() {
  $("#filename").text(this.files[0].name);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="file-label">
   <input class="file-input" type="file" name="image" id="imgInp">
   <span class="file-cta">
       <span class="file-icon"><i class="fas fa-upload"></i></span>
        <span class="file-label">image</span>
   </span>
   <span class="file-name" id="filename"></span>
</label>
```

But it didn't work and give me an error

```
TypeError: $(...)[0] is undefined
```

Comment: non of that solutions work for me .. the same error

Comment: Your code seems to work for me. Are you able to reproduce the error in the snippet above?

Comment: yes it works in the snippet

Comment: Are you sure that the code you posted matches the code that throws the error? The reason I ask is because your code doesn't seem to contain anything like `$(...)[0]`.

Comment: ooooh my mistake .. you right the  $(...)[0] refer to another part  .. it works now .. thank you so much